# Else statement does not get executed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I've been trying to write a function to validate a string value. My code is below

```
function verifyPassword(){
passW = prompt ("Password:");

if (passW = 'Pass123'){
  document.write ('Your password is correct');
}
else {

  document.write ('Your password is incorrect');
}
}

verifyPassword();
```

But here I always seem to get the result as 'Your password is correct', no matter what I put.

Please can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: you are doing an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: `passW = 'Pass123'` is always true, and should have been `passW == 'Pass123'`, which makes this question a simple typographic error, which is off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do

```
function verifyPassword(){
passW = prompt ("Password:");

if (passW == 'Pass123'){
  document.write ('Your password is correct');
}
else {

  document.write ('Your password is incorrect');
}
}

verifyPassword();
```

Answer (score 2):

The comparation-operator in Javascript is `==`. The `=` operator is for assignment and returns the assigned value. So your code is equivalent to:

```
passW = 'Pass123';
if (passW){
  document.write ('Your password is correct');
}
```

Use `if (passW == 'Pass123')` instead.

By the way, I hope you are not *really* trying to implement authentication and access control with client-sided javascript.

Comment: No it's just a simple example